# fault in code pls rectify.PLS HELP. Beginner in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I was working with python and wrote down some this sort of code. According to me it should be false but it is showing true.

```
list1=[1,2,3,4]
list2=[2,3,1]
list3=[5,6,7]
if 1 in list1 and list3:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```py
list1=[1,2,3,4]
list2=[2,3,1]
list3=[5,6,7]
if 1 in list1 and 1 in list3:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

that's the pythonic way of checking,

`if 1 in list1 and list3` means that `1 in list1` which is True ,`and list3`
is the second part which will always be true until the list is not empty
thus it becomes
`if True and True`
so it returns True
hope you understood :D

Btw there are more ways of checking if a particular item belongs to multiple lists

```py
list1=[1,2,3,4]
list2=[2,3,1]
list3=[5,6,7]
if all(1 in lis for lis in [list1,list3]):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```